# Angular JS Factory shared in two controllers does not update value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to Angular, so forgive me, but I have this as my index.html:

```
<body>
    <div data-ng-controller="storeList">
        <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="c.CustomerID as c.CustomerName for c in customers"
        ng-change="changeCust(selectedItem)">
            <option value="">Select Store</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div data-ng-controller="storeInfo">
        Selected Store is: {{selectedStore}}
    </div>
</body>
```

and this for my js:

```
var storeApp = angular.module('storeApp',[])
storeApp.factory('currentCustomer',function($http) {
return {
    customerID :0,
    getCustomers: function () {
        console.log("in get")
        return [{CustomerID:1,CustomerName:'Store 1'},
                {CustomerID:2,CustomerName:'Store 2'},
                {CustomerID:3,CustomerName:'Store 3'}]

                }
    }


});


    storeApp.controller('storeList',function($scope,$http,currentCustomer) {
    $scope.customers = currentCustomer.getCustomers()


    $scope.changeCust = function changeCust(id) {
        console.log("Changing ID from: "+ currentCustomer.customerID)
        currentCustomer.customerID = id
        console.log("ID Is now: " + currentCustomer.customerID)
    }

    });
    storeApp.controller('storeInfo',function($scope,currentCustomer) {
    console.log("Setting up storeInfo")
    $scope.man = 'Rob';
    $scope.selectedStore = currentCustomer.customerID;
});
```

When I change the select, the `currentCustomer.customerID` changes but does not update in the `storeInfo` controller.

What am I missing.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not going to update because when you do

```
$scope.selectedStore = currentCustomer.customerID;
```

you create new property `selectedStore` with value equal to `currentCustomer.customerID`, but there is no connection (no reference) between them. When original changes it will not reflect in the second.

The simple solution is to use object references:

```
$scope.selectedStore = currentCustomer;
```

and use `{{selectedStore.customerID}}` afterwards.

Comment: thanks you for your explanation on that, it worked. Makes sense now that I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

The two binding does not work with primitive data types as there is no reference to bind them and listen changes on them. 
You can assign the currentCustomer object to the selectedStore scope variable and this way you can listen to changes in both the controllers.

I have done some minor refactoring to Factory instance for better readability and understanding -

```js
var storeApp = angular.module('storeApp',[]);
storeApp.factory('currentCustomer',function() {
    var customerId = 0;

    function getCustomerId()
    {
        return customerId;
    }

    function setCustomerId(id)
    {
        customerId = id;
    }

    return {
        getCustomerId : getCustomerId,
        setCustomerId : setCustomerId,
        getCustomers: function () {
            console.log("in get")
            return [{CustomerID:1,CustomerName:'Store 1'},
                {CustomerID:2,CustomerName:'Store 2'},
                {CustomerID:3,CustomerName:'Store 3'}]

        }
    }


});


storeApp.controller('storeList',function($scope,$http,currentCustomer) {
    $scope.customers = currentCustomer.getCustomers();


    $scope.changeCust = function changeCust(id) {
        console.log("Changing ID from: "+ currentCustomer.getCustomerId())
        currentCustomer.setCustomerId(id);
        console.log("ID Is now: " + currentCustomer.getCustomerId())
    }

});
storeApp.controller('storeInfo',function($scope,currentCustomer) {
    console.log("Setting up storeInfo");
    $scope.man = 'Rob';
    $scope.selectedStore = currentCustomer;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="storeApp">
<div data-ng-controller="storeList">
    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="c.CustomerID as c.CustomerName for c in customers"
            ng-change="changeCust(selectedItem)">
        <option value="">Select Store</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div data-ng-controller="storeInfo">
    Selected Store is: {{selectedStore.getCustomerId()}}
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If one still want to use the 
$scope.selectedStore = currentCustomer.customerID;

here is the another approach.

Inter controller communication in Angularjs can be achieved using the following mechanisms.

1. Using the $rootScope
2. By Using one of the mechanism for creating the custom services in Angularjs.
   These are...
    a) Factory Method
    b) Value Method
    c) Service Method or
    d) Provide Method.

In this article we will use the factory method for inter controller communication in Angularjs

Please have a look at the post 
http://yogeshtutorials.blogspot.in/2015/11/inter-controller-communication-in.html

Here is the refactored code

HTML

```
  <div data-ng-controller="storeList">
        <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="c.CustomerID as c.CustomerName for c in customers"
        ng-change="changeCust(selectedItem)">
            <option value="">Select Store</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div data-ng-controller="storeInfo">
        Selected Store is: {{selectedStore}}
    </div>
```

JS:

```
var storeApp = angular.module('storeApp',[])
storeApp.factory('currentCustomer',function($rootScope) {
  var currentCustomer =  {};
  currentCustomer.customerID = 0;
  currentCustomer.customerName = '';
      currentCustomer.getCustomers =  function () {
          return [{CustomerID:1,CustomerName:'Store 1'},
                  {CustomerID:2,CustomerName:'Store 2'},
                  {CustomerID:3,CustomerName:'Store 3'}]; 
      };
      currentCustomer.setCurrentCustomer = function (custObject) {
        this.customerID = custObject['CustomerID'];
        this.ustomerName = custObject['CustomerName'];
        this.publishChanges();
      }; 

      currentCustomer.getCustomerID = function(){
        return this.customerID;
      };

      currentCustomer.getCustomerName = function(){
        return this.customerName; 
      };      
      currentCustomer.publishChanges = function() {
              $rootScope.$broadcast('custDataChangeEvent');
      };
    return currentCustomer; 
});  

    storeApp.controller('storeList',function($scope,$http,currentCustomer,$filter) {
      $scope.customers = currentCustomer.getCustomers();
      $scope.changeCust = function changeCust(id) {
          var filteredCustomerList = $filter('filter')($scope.customers,{CustomerID:id},true);
          var currCustomer = filteredCustomerList[0];
          currentCustomer.setCurrentCustomer(currCustomer);
      };

    });
      storeApp.controller('storeInfo',function($scope,currentCustomer) {
      // listen to the events
      $scope.$on('custDataChangeEvent',function(){
       $scope.selectedStore = currentCustomer.getCustomerID();
      });
});
```

Comment: Another way to is to use the provider recipe like value or factory to achieve this     
Please refer to my post for the complete details. [http://yogeshtutorials.blogspot.in/2015/11/session-tracking-in-angularjs.html](http://yogeshtutorials.blogspot.in/2015/11/session-tracking-in-angularjs.html)